# Concurrent requests are not permitted in specific time period

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In my web API, the client wants me to implement logic in order to control/block concurrent requests in a specific time period. I added RequestInterval which is 10 seconds in the appsettings of web config. I added the Authorization filter into my project. I tested, it looks working but I wonder if you can check and give me some feedback.

```
public class ValidIntervalFilter : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            double sec = Double.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RequestInterval"].ToString());
            DateTime lastDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime requestDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            var terminal_number = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["shopNo"];
            using (GameContext ctx = new GameContext())
            {
                //this will throw an exception
                var lastRequestTime = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<DateTime>(
                    "SELECT MAX([RequestDateTime]) FROM GameRequests WHERE[ShopNo] = @shopNo and RequestDateTime >= CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())",
                    new SqlParameter("shopNo", terminal_number)).ToList();

                foreach (var time in lastRequestTime)
                {
                    lastDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(time);
                }
                DateTime timeAfterInterval = lastDateTime.AddSeconds(sec);
                if (requestDateTime <= timeAfterInterval)
                {
                    var response = new HttpResponseMessage
                    {
                        StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)429,
                        ReasonPhrase = "Too Many Requests",
                        Content = new StringContent("Concurrent requests are NOT permitted in " + sec + " seconds.")

                    };

                    actionContext.Response = response;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**I changed the query and here is the updated code:**

```
public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            double sec = Double.Parse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RequestInterval"].ToString());

            var terminal_number = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["shopNo"];
            using (GameContext ctx = new GameContext())
            {

                var lastRequestTime = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>(
                    "SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, [RequestDateTime], GETDATE()) As [SecondsSinceLastRequest] FROM [dbo].[GameRequests] WHERE [ShopNo] = @shopNo AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, [RequestDateTime], GETDATE() ) < @delay",
                    new SqlParameter("shopNo", terminal_number), new SqlParameter("delay", sec)).ToList();

                if (lastRequestTime.Count > 0)
                {
                    var response = new HttpResponseMessage
                    {
                        StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)429,
                        ReasonPhrase = "Too Many Requests",
                        Content = new StringContent("Concurrent requests are NOT permitted in " + sec + " seconds.")

                    };

                    actionContext.Response = response;
                }

            }
        }
```